# How to index only relevant fields of my model using Algolia search?

Tags: mongodb, algolia

I am incorporating Algolia search in one of my applications and running into the 10 KB document size limit. I only want to index certain fields within my model and not the whole thing. I am using mongo and it has embedded and related documents that I dont care for.

I followed the instructions at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout

Now when I index the data, I get the warnings that about 100 out of my 2000 or so documents are over the 10 KB size.

How do I tell Algolia that I only want to index certain fields and ignore some of the other data like relationships or embedded documents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toSearchableArray` of Laravel in the class you're adding the searchable trait. In that you only include the parts that you actually want to search on.

```
public function toSearchableArray() {
  $array = $this->toArray();
  $array = [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'description' => $this->description,
    'price' => (int)$this->price,
    'likes' => (int)$this->likes,
    'slug' => $this->slug
  ];
  return $array;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Note that the array must be returned at the end